# Uncaught TypeError: no implicit conversion of NilClass into Hash when loading page Ruby Volt

Tags: voltrb

When loading a page, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: no implicit conversion of NilClass into Hash
```

I am using the volt framework for ruby. My routes file inside of the component is as follows:

```
client '/summary_reporting/daily_reports/new', component: 'summary_reporting', controller: 'daily_reports', action: 'new'
```

My controller and view are correctly made and declared and the component was generated using:

```
bundle exec volt generate component summary_reporting
```

Can anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just fixed an issue that was similar to this.  Are you loading the url with a #fragment ?  If thats not it, any chance you can post the code somewhere so I can try it and figure out what the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just needed to include the new component in the main dependencies file.